# JQuery insertBefore makes duplicates instead of updating it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so i wanted to create a simple and secure contact form really fast, so i just googled it and found this [template](http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/create-a-simple-and-secure-contact-form-with-jquery-and-php/)
and tried to merge it with my code :

```
<article>
<div id='errord'></div>
<div id="wrap">
    <form id="contactform" action="processForm.php" method="post">
        <input placeholder="نام" type="text" id="name" name="name" />
        <input placeholder="ایمیل" type="text" id="email" name="email" />
        <textarea placeholder="پیام شما" id="message" name="message" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="ارسال" id="send" /> 
    </form>
    <div id="response"></div>
</div>
```

but Icant get it to work , it form has a validation which shows error like fill that input or that email fomat is wrong , in is orginal form it work just fine but in mu code (HTML edited dont want table stuff) intead of updating the mesaages it just keeps inserting more error saying the error several times,I mean, error code

js code where is updated the error message :

```
  $('#contactform').validate({
    // Specify what the errors should look like
    // when they are dynamically added to the form
    errorElement: "p",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertBefore( element.parent() );
        error.wrap("<div class='error' id='errord'></div>");        
    }
it's a part of a bigger function ... (slightly modified)
```

I tried different approches but i couldnt get it to work 100% im good with html and css but just never tried advanced js stuff.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure i have understood the problem but you can have look this simple form and compeer with yours.

    https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimince/w9m34afa/

Comment: @Ibrahimİnce hmm let me give you an example : you click submit without putting any data in form , you get three error messages telling you to fill the form , if you click submit again you get three me error messages , now you have 6 of them instead of 3 , it is supposed to erase prior error but it doesn't , if you click more or even try to type in fields (it seems to have some kind of on input content change event) you keep getting more and more errors adding to previous ones